# Are future tenses used in relative clauses?

Tags: modal-verbs, relative-clauses

Are future tenses used in relative clauses?
e.g.

1. He is a person who(that) **will** listen to everybody.
2. He'll work with his brother who(that) **will** explain evrything to him.

Are these clauses correct?

Comment: You can use any tense you want in a relative clause! There are no special rules about tenses for relative clauses ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the future tense in a relative clause and both your examples are grammatically correct.

According to [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+will+listen%2C+that+will+explain&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthat%20will%20listen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20will%20explain%3B%2Cc0) there’s no such a restriction.